# Primefaces button ajax false

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un botón en primefaces:

```
<p:commandButton value="Exportar fichero" 
action="#{exportarView.exporta}"
ajax="false">
```

El método construye un excel y lo devuelve, todo esto funciona bien, el problema lo tengo al hacer una validación y no devolver el excel, que se me queda la patalla en blanco.

Mi Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="exportar")
@ViewScoped
public class Exportar implements Serializable {

    public void execute() throws IOException{

        if(validacion) {

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

        //Relleno excel ...
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Mh.xlsx\"");

        workbook.write(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());

        facesContext.responseComplete();
        } else {
            //¿Que poner?
        }
    }
}
```

¿Qué debo poner dentro del `else` para que retorne de forma normal?

Comment: `JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Este reporte no fue generado");`
            `return null;` prueba esto en el else

Comment: Puedes mandar un *flash message*: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().put("validation", "Mensaje de validación"); return "mismaPagina";` Y en tu vista: `<h: messages />`.

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido con `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(pagina.xhtml");`